# Diagonal entries of a negative definite matrix

Tags: matrices

If a matrix $A$ is known to be negative definite, can we somehow imply based on that info that all the diagonal entries are negative? Is it proven through eigenvalues or is there some other way to show that?

Comment: Modify [Sylvester’s criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

Answer (score 7):

Consider $e_k^T\cdot A\cdot e_k$, where $e_k$ is the $k$th standard basis vector. Since $A$ is negative definite, that's negative. But then, calculating it directly, it's the $k$th diagonal entry.